# How can I notify database update using web api in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working on Web API project for one of my web application using Asp.Net technology. The API will be an open API for different customers to use.

One of my customer who is going to use the API has a request wherein they want to poll the database and fetch all the information related to their customers and not just updated ones every 'x' interval. I feel its a very expensive call to make. Well we are still discussing on the best option possible.

Is their any alternative approach where in I can just sent updated records to my client and not all the records from all the data tables in the database?

Any help would be great as I am new in using ASP.NET technology.

Comment: Your customer wants "all the information ...not just updated ones" yet you're asking how to "just sent updated records"?  I'm confused.

Comment: Well we are still discussing on the best option possible. I have updated the question too.

Comment: It sounds like your customer wants real time access to any changes made to their customer info in your database. If you want to go down the route of 'pushing' new data to your customers, would you consider having them build a web service and make them register the endpoints with you? You then develop an application to POST the data (ie: json) to that clients registered endpoint every time there is an update for that client.

Comment: set up a message queue and every time a record is updated, either copy the update to the queue or identify the record that has been updated. Then the client would read the message queue, whenever they want, to get the updates.

Comment: Message Queue sounds like a good option. Can I get some more reference/tutorial for good way to implement this in asp.net? Also I am not sure what kind of technology my customer is using and I don't want to make the message queuing system dependent on  client system. thanks

Comment: Given you're using asp.net you could look into using SignalR for this too. It provides exactly what you're looking for, but would be something your client would have to be okay using of course.

Comment: How about using RabbitMQ?